# Best practice for modifiers of constructor in Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Now, I'm reading [Guice's official document.](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/KeepConstructorsHidden)  And they say

> As a correction, simply limit the visibility of both your
> implementation classes, and their constructors. Typically package
> private is preferred for both, as this facilitates:
>
> binding the class within a Module in the same package
>
> unit testing the class through means of direct instantiation
>
> As a simple, mnemonic
> remember that public and @Inject are like Elves and Dwarfs: they can
> work together, but in an ideal world, they would coexist
> independently.

I know how dangerous `public constructor` is by reading the document.
And the quoted sentence appears to be the solution, but I am not sure of the exact meaning.
So, could you check whether my thought is right or not.

First, they say **binding the class within a Module in the same package**.
This means for example you have a package in a system.  And it is good to use a `Module` corresponding with the package?  So, basically you have the same number of `Module`s and same number of packages?

Second, you can see **unit testing the class through means of direct instantiation**.
This means we should do unit testing a class using direct instantiation, not `Guice`'s `Module`?
I think `Guice` is also useful for a testing, especially unit testing as they said.

I am confused a little bit, could anyone make me clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First, they say binding the class within a Module in the same package. This means for example you have a package in a system. And it is good to use a Module corresponding with the package? So, basically you have the same number of Modules and same number of packages?

Yes. You should always be using packages anyway. Use of the default package is discouraged for all but toy-sized programs.

I would typically expect to have a `org.whatever.foo.some.feature` package with a module class called `FeatureModule` (i.e. the name of the package + `Module`, not specifically `FeatureModule`).

> Second, you can see unit testing the class through means of direct instantiation. This means we should do unit testing a class using direct instantiation, not Guice's Module? I think Guice is also useful for a testing, especially unit testing as they said.

It's just easier to see exactly what you're testing with if you directly inject the things you want to test with.

Sure, you can use guice, but there's a certain amount of "magic happens here" with the bindings, which can hide unexpected behaviour in the test.

This applies to *unit testing*; if you're doing integration testing, you likely do want to be using something close to how your production code does it, which may involve guice.